# Dropping event because there is no touchable window at (x, y)

Tags: android, events, touch

I'm developing a music player application. There are three ways to change tracks:

1. Bottom bar - these are just default buttons
2. Swiping cover pictures from one to another direction with gestures
3. Selecting a cover from a coverflow

For the second option I use a `ViewPager`.
For the third option I use a custom library, named `FancyCoverFlow`
(https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow/tree/master/library).

I receive these kind of log messages on logcat, when I try to change tracks with either option 2 or 3:

> 01-08 13:04:08.047    1255-1287/system_process I/InputDispatcher﹕
> Dropping event because there is no touchable window at (-727, 352).
>
> 01-08 13:04:08.627    1255-1287/system_process I/InputDispatcher﹕
> Dropping event because there is no touchable window at (-727, 352).
>
> 01-08 13:04:08.783    1255-1287/system_process I/InputDispatcher﹕
> Dropping event because there is no touchable window at (-604, 659).

No other logs I receive with logcat.
Could you explain, what I'm experiencing?

Comment: is your issue fixed? If yes, can you share the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no solution has been found since then.

Answer (score 0):

I falsely set the `addTextChangedListener` of EditText to `null` which resulted in the same mistake. I fixed it, and the mistake had gone. Hope it would help.